# Let f be continuous with $|f(x)| = 1$ $\forall$ $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $f$ is either $f(x) = 1$ or $f(x) = -1$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: analysis, functions

Let f be continuous with $|f(x)| = 1$ $\forall$ $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Show either $f(x) = 1$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ or $f(x) = -1$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I know that the first step of the solution will be $(-1 < f(x) < 1)$, however this already implies that $f(x) = 1$ or $f(x) = -1$, so I am unsure how you would prove this result.

Comment: You must have some additional assumption, otherwise it's not true. Is it given that $f$ is continuous, for example? (And is $f$ real-valued, as opposed to complex-valued?)

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is continuous, use the fact that the image of a connected set is connected since $f(x)\in\{-1,1\}$

Answer (score 0):

By the Intermediate Value Theorem, if there exist $a$ and $b$ such that $f(a)=-1$ and $f(b)=1$, then there must exist $c$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $f(c)=0$, which is ruled out by the hypothesis.

Comment: I know the proof will involve the intermediate value theorem, but since we have the absolute value of $f(x)$ I'm unsure how what you've said will help